# Requirejs-config.js not working for parent theme's responsive.js file

Tags: requirejs, magento2.3, rwd, requirejs-config.js, mixins

I would like to change the values for the `media` property for the files [menu.js](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/lib/web/mage/menu.js) & [responsive.js](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/design/frontend/Magento/blank/Magento_Theme/web/js/responsive.js) from `media: '(min-width: 768px)'` to `media: '(min-width: 992px)'`.

I thought using Magento's [JS Mixin approach](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html) would be best as instead overriding these files entirly, with this approach I should be able to just change the `media` property.

So I created the `requirejs-config.js` file in my theme below, but it does't work.  It does not load the mixin files from my theme or give any errors in the browser console.

`app/design/frontend/Namespace/mytheme/Magento_Theme/requirejs-config.js`

```
"use strict";
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Theme/js/responsive': {
                'Magento_Theme/js/responsive-mixin': true
            },
            'lib/web/mage/menu': {
                'Magento_Theme/js/menu-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

`app/design/frontend/Namespace/mytheme/Magento_Theme/web/js/responsive-mixin.js`

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'matchMedia',
    'mage/tabs',
    'domReady!'
], function ($, mediaCheck) {
    'use strict';

    var mixin = {

        media: '(min-width: 992px)'
    };

    return function (target) {
        return target.extend(mixin);
    };
});
```

I have cleared the cache and remove the static files.
i.e.

```
bin/magento cache:clean
rm -rf pub/static/frontend/ var/view_preprocessed/
```

I'm not sure what else to do?  Is it not possible to write a mixin for these files?  Is there another approach I can take. Ideally, I would prefer not to have to overide the files entirely in my theme.

### UPDATE

I have noticed if I try to add a mixin for another file it works...
i.e.

```
"use strict";
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm': {
                'Magento_Theme/js/test-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

So is it that [JS Mixins](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html) do not work for JS files which come from a parent theme or `/lib` directory?

Also, another way I can change the breakpoint in menu.js is to override the template in my theme and passing `"mediaBreakpoint": "(max-width: 992px)"` as one of the options

`app/design/frontend/Namespace/mytheme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/topmenu.phtml`

```
<?php $columnsLimit = $block->getColumnsLimit() ?: 0; ?>

<?php $_menu = $block->getHtml('level-top', 'submenu', $columnsLimit) ?>
<nav class="navigation" data-action="navigation">
    <ul data-mage-init='{"menu":{"mediaBreakpoint": "(max-width: 992px)", "responsive":true, "expanded":true, "position":{"my":"left top","at":"left bottom"}}}'>
        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_menu ?>
        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getChildHtml() ?>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue with the mixin for [menu.js](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/lib/web/mage/menu.js).  It should use `mage/menu` rather than `lib/web/mage/menu'`

```
"use strict";
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'mage/menu': {
                'Magento_Theme/js/menu-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

And then in the `menu-mixin.js` file I have.

```
define([], function () {
    return function (widget) {
        widget.menu.prototype.options.mediaBreakpoint = "(max-width: 992px)";

        return widget;
    };
});
```

**I'm still having the issue with Magento_Theme/js/responsive though, I think this may be because it is initialised in the deps block of parent theme's (blank) requirejs-config file rather than within a define block or with data-mage-init.**